# Java application running in Eclipse but not as standalone jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have built a java application using spring-boot and maven. When I am running this application from eclipse it is running perfectly fine,  but when I try to run this application as a standalone jar through `java -jar`, it is giving me this error

> Error
>
> ```
> o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'placeRefillOrderControllerImpl': 
>  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'placeRefillOrderService'; nested exception is 
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException 
>  Error creating bean with name 'placeRefillOrderServiceImpl': 
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'placeRefillOrderBiz'; nested exception is 
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'placeRefillOrderBizImpl': 
>      Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'placeRefillOrderConnector'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'getConnector': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'refillOrderRequestTransformer'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>  Error creating bean with name 'refillOrderRequestTransformer': 
>   Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is 
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.sams.pharmacy.soapconnector.helper.RefillOrderRequestTransformer] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@439f5b3d]
> ```

Comment: `com.sams.pharmacy.soapconnector.helper.RefillOrderRequestTransformer` When running the project in Eclipse, do you have the project containg this class opened?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). 
please [add](/help/editing) 
a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Prattek  are you looking for a packaging mechanism that allows you to wrap everthing into a single a file, like a jar? In netbeans this process can be easely archived by following the UI (that takes you far away from all the details regarding the packaing process). In Eclipse i don't recall it has one. But if you look for "packaging jar for redistribution" i guess you will find what you need!

Comment: Please follow this steps and share us the result : #1 open a shell pointing to your source code. # execute : mvn clean package spring-boot:run